# Create meta-annotation for @KafkaListener

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create custom meta-annotation based on the @KafkaListener annotation but spring-kafka throws an error.

Here's my annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@KafkaListener
public @interface MessageListener {
  @AliasFor(annotation = KafkaListener.class, attribute = "topics")
  String[] value() default {};
}
```

My consumer service:

```
@EnableKafka
public class CarSubscriber extends BaseSubscriber<String, Car> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(CarSubscriber.class);

    @MyMessageListener("${kafka.topic.car}")
    public void receiveMessage(Car car) {

       LOGGER.info("received car=" + car.toString());
       getLatch().countDown();
    }
}
```

Error stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An array of topicPartitions must be provided
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties.<init>(ContainerProperties.java:175) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.<init>(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:130) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.<init>(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:69) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createContainerInstance(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:70) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createContainerInstance(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:40) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:177) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:46) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.createListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:183) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:155) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:129) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.registerAllEndpoints(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:138) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:132) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:230) ~[spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:781) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
```

Actually, I want to specify the topic name inside my meta annotation, in other words inside @MyMessageListener as shown above. But it does not work.

Am I doing something wrong or is Spring-kafka just not supporting @AliasFor annotations for @KafkaListener? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @ @MyMessageListener(topics="${kafka.topic.car}") instead of

@MyMessageListener("${kafka.topic.car}").